# Magento_Amqp and Magento_MysqlMq errors during setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2.3.4, setup-upgrade, porto-theme

I have M2.3.4 and Porto 3.2.3 installed. I've recently changed Quickview modules and now when I run setup:upgrade, i get 2 errors:

Magento_Amqp: Topic "inventory.source.items.cleanup" is not configured
Magento_MysqlMq: Error while checking if topic is synchronous

I see that this has to do with Magento messaging but have no idea why I would get these messages all of a sudden.

In the system.log, I see this message:
main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*I faced this issue and solved by. Also the checkout was unable to load the shipping method. I tried below to solve the issue.*

```
composer update
```

Finally run flush and redeploy.